# Adding a entry to a csv file throws error:does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: powershell

I have a `.csv` file like this:

```
"LastWriteTime","BackupFile","MountedDrive"
"07:07 Fri Mar 03 23","c:\temp\xxx01-01.mrimg","A"
"08:07 Fri Mar 03 23","c:\temp\xxx01-02.mrimg","B"
"09:07 Fri Mar 03 23","c:\temp\xxx01-03.mrimg","C"
```

Its a logging file, I have a function that adds a entry to it every time it does something, here is a snippet from the function:

```
$Log = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Logging.csv"

$NewLogEntry = [PSCustomObject]@{
  LastWriteTime = $Path.LastWriteTime.ToString('hh:mm ddd MMM dd yy')
  BackupFile    = $path
  MountedDrive  = $Drive.ToUpper()
}

$Log += $NewLogEntry
$Log | ConvertTo-Csv | Set-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Logging.csv" -Force
```

This line `$Log += $NewLogEntry` seems to throw an error randomly, it will sometimes work and but mostly throw an error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:24 char:12
+     $Var = $Log += $NewLogEntry
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
```

Looking it up, I found answers suggesting its to do with `$log` not being overwritten, so I tried:

```
$Log2 = Log+= $NewLogEntry
$Log2 | ConvertTo-Csv | Set-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Logging.csv" -Force
```

Still fails.

Completely stuck. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error happens when your CSV **only has one row**, the output from `Import-Csv` gets enumerated when assigned to a variable, if the CSV happens to have only one row, then the variable would be of the type `PSObject` instead of `object[]` and `+=` would fail in that case because `PSObject` doesn't have an `op_Addition` imlementation defined.

Easy way to reproduce the error:

```bash
([pscustomobject]@{ foo = 123 }) + ([pscustomobject]@{ foo = 123 })
```

To overcome this you could use the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-) so `$Log` would always be an `object[]`:

```bash
$Log = @(Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Logging.csv")
```

However, a much easier approach would be to simply use `-Append`, that way there is no need to import the CSV:

```bash
# No `Import-Csv` needed

[PSCustomObject]@{
  LastWriteTime = $Path.LastWriteTime.ToString('hh:mm ddd MMM dd yy')
  BackupFile    = $path
  MountedDrive  = $Drive.ToUpper()
} | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\Logging.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: Excellent, I was having so much headache micro managing this csv. To just append to it is genius. thanks so much!!